# What's the meaning of "crash on international shores"?

Tags: phrase-meaning

> Zhou Haohui, the latest author to catch the wave of Chinese crime
>   fiction **crashing on international shores**, had an unsatisfying job
>   teaching engineering at a university outside of Beijing in 2007 when
>   he began publishing —,  online —,  the novels that would earn him a
>   cultlike following in China.

[Source](https://www.nytimes.com/2018/06/04/books/zhou-haohui-death-notice-chinese-crime-thrillers.html)

Comment: As James says, **waves crash** on the shore, but the metaphor is being mangled here.  Surfers "catch" waves and ride them and bail (or at least they try to do so)  long before the waves crash. And which shores are the "international shores"? The shores of China?  How could the author being catching waves on foreign shores?

Comment: I don't think it's mangled. Apparently there is a large amount of Chinese crime fiction now being sold to countries outside of China (international means non-chinese in this context) When there is such a wave, authors who would not have been known outside [china] can be carried by the wave. In the metaphor the wave travels from China to the other countries, so the author (metaphorically) catches it in China and his work is carried to other countries.

Comment: I didn't realize there was an international audience for Chinese crime fiction. I still think it's a strained metaphor. He's riding the wave in multiple directions for one thing, and the wave shouldn't be described as **crashing**.  You cannot be in China and catch a wave that is **crashing on foreign shores**.  The wave could be **heading** for foreign shores.  The wave metaphor is taken too far.  **catch** and **crashing** don't belong together. As you say, "when a wave reaches land it crashes".

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's a metaphor. It extends the "wave" metaphor.

The large amount of Chinese crime fiction is metaphorically a "wave"

This wave is now reaching other countries. When a wave reaches land it crashes onto the shore.

Comment: I see. I have thought "crash" was a negative word, that means some bad thing happens.